# Can I use Edge 510 as an indoor trainer computer

Tags: training, garmin, bike-computer

I'm setting up for the winter (yes it's only October, this is Sweden).

I need to set up a speedometer for my rear wheel while I use the turbo trainer, I have a Garmin Edge 510 with cadence sensor, and wonder can I set this up to feed cadence and speed (with speed taken from the rear wheel) to the Edge head unit whilst on a stationary trainer?

How do I set the edge computer to deal with this (I assume it needs to know to take speed from the sensor and not GPS, and just trying to use it as normal failed).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm basing this on my 810 but I assume they're similar.

You can create a new profile for riding on the turbo. For each profile you can select which sensors are used. If you turn off GPS and turn on cadence and speed (and HR if you have it) you can use it indoors. You might need another sensor to pick up wheel speed if you only have a cadence sensor. A combined (speed and cadence) one is around £35 in the UK, not sure what they'd be in Sweden.

I don't have it on me at the moment. If you need more details I'll post instructions based on mine this evening.

Comment: @GriffinEvo That sounds about right to me. Also, I have access to an online manual for my 800 through my.garmin.com - it would surprise me if you couldn't see a 510 manual there

Comment: Tried it last night, speed was a bit off and I couldn't find the setting for that while riding last night, I will take a look at the manual (thanks @PeteH).

Comment: @GriffinEvo Speed was a bit off compared to what?

Comment: Just low, it was saying the wheel was doing ~8-10 km/h, I know its more than that (also ran an old cycling computer with the right wheel size set and it read 25-30 km/h, I just need to set the wheel size)

Answer (score 2):

I have a Garmin 510 unit with a GSC-10 speed/cadence sensor.

If you don't already have a seperate cadence sensor installed, a combined speed/cadence sensor like the GSC-10 from Garmin (or any other ANT+ sensor from other manufacturers) is the easiest. Just pair the sensor to your unit as per manual and you're good to go.

However, you should realize that using speed/distance data on the trainer only makes sense if you keep the resistance level constant (variations can occur due to changing tire pressure, weight and/or movement).